# JSON documentation

Tags: java, json

I am building a servlet which responses with a json message.The problem is that i cant found documentation about how to create and how to parse the messages.Can someone give me a simple example of json message creation and parsing?
Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Just curious: how did you manage not to find documentation about this? Did you try googling JSON Java?

Comment: It was really late the night i asked this question so i couldn't think clearly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some good documentation and links over at [json.org](http://json.org/).

But, for good measure, here's some json:

```
{
    "Title" : "Content",
    "Another Title" : ["An", "Array"],
    "Life, the Universe and Everything" : 42
}
```

You can also play around on [this site](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to see what its going to look like.

Comment: My problem is that when i receive the message i cant extract the information from it.Maybe because its a bit late in my country i am unable to understand!Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: I would recommend taking the JSON you are getting back and putting it into http://json.parser.online.fr/ to try and see if its valid. If it is, Java should support it with their JSON integration.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be [good Java support](http://www.json.org/java/) for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

http://json.org/ gives a full description of JSON that is pretty easy to understand.

But, yes, as @nikosdi pointed out, Java and almost all languages support JSON very well now so you shouldn't have to do any more than place the JSON inside a wrapper object and access the JSON properties that way.